# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or

Tags: reactjs, upgrade

After upgrade react16.14.0, react-dom16.14.0, node-sass6.0.0
I am new to react I do not know how to debug it it does not show the file that error occurs in .. I solved it in many places that shows the file but now I could not

[please check the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWGuP.png)

Comment: As the error message says, it's probably caused by an incorrect import. If you want to attempt to figure out which import, you'll need to show us the code.

Comment: Ok, we'll still need to see the code. The stack trace says the issue is in `Component`.

Comment: If you can't share the code, then you will need to debug it yourself. Go to the last component in that stack trace that you wrote (i'm guessing `GuestNavbar`), and look in there. Try adding console.log statements for every component that it uses. One of them is `undefined`, and that's causing the problem.

Comment: allah bless u you save me <3 <3 <3

Comment: @NicholasTower could you check the screenshot again I face this error in a lot of places.. this time does not show me the file that is occurs in

Comment: I solve this error with checking all imports in all components until I found the home components (by pressing on the importing if it goes to the component .. then importing is right)

Comment: if u install package start with ^ go to package-lock.json and be sure that all modules come from the same version if not go to the page u stuck in and try to go with ctrl+enter on every module u imported one of them u will not go to check this module u will find that it is installed with another version go and delete node_modules and package-lock.json and delete this ^ and install it should work successfully .. please like my answer if it works